# Canceling setState update gives type assignment error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a custom React hook for my components with more complex state. It's basically a normal `useState` hook but with 2 extra features: it checks for equality and prevents a re-render, and it merges the state instead of replacing it. I need to return `null` from `setState` in order to cancel the state update, but TypeScript won't allow me. I get the following error:

```
Argument of type '(prevState: K) => (K & Partial<K>) | null' is not 
assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<K>'.
  Type '(prevState: K) => (K & Partial<K>) | null' is not 
  assignable to type '(prevState: K) => K'.
    Type '(K & Partial<K>) | null' is not assignable to type 'K'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'K'.ts(2345)
```

My hook looks like this:

```js
export function useNestedState<K extends UnknownObject>( // UnknownObject = {[key: string]: any}
  initialState: K,
): [K, (newState: Partial<K>) => void] {
  const [state, setState] = useState<K>(initialState);

  const setNestedState = useCallback((newState: Partial<K>) => {
    setState((prevState) => {
      return comparePartialObject(prevState, newState) // Returns `true` if equal
        ? null // Will cancel state update
        : { ...prevState, ...newState };
    });
  }, []);

  return [state, setNestedState];
}
```

Can anyone please help me solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

When the comparePartialObject gets true, then you are not cancelling state update, instead, you are updating the state with null. As the state is type of 'K', it throws error, that you cannot set state of type 'K' to null.
This code will work

```
setState((prevState) => {
      return comparePartialObject(prevState, newState) // Returns `true` if equal
        ? prevState // Will not change the old state
        : { ...prevState, ...newState };
    });
```